# How to convert imported CSV file data into JSON objects using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, file

**I am having difficulty how to convert csv file data into json objects.But I am getting uncaught TypeError: e.split is not a function Here is my code.**
HTML Code:

```
 <input type="file" accept=".csv" onchange="onFileChange()" />
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
function onFileChange(event) {
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = e => e.target.result;
  reader.onload = e => {
    console.log(e.target.result);
    var lines = e.target.result.split("\n");
    var result = [];

    // NOTE: If your columns contain commas in their values, you'll need
    // to deal with those before doing the next step 
    // (you might convert them to &&& or something, then covert them back later)
    // jsfiddle showing the issue https://jsfiddle.net/
    var headers = lines[0].split(",");

    for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
      var obj = {};
      var currentline = lines[i].split(",");
      for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }
      result.push(obj);
    }

    //return result; //JavaScript object
    return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

**Note: I have tried every possible code on stackoverflow, but I did not get what I want. I hope you can help me. Thanks**

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call a method `split` on a [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event), but the event does not have such a method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example JavaScript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1293147/438273)

Comment: I have edited my code. The error is gone. But still I am having issue to convert it into json objects.